Why do I see TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default().models is undefined
I'm building a bidding system using Nextjs 14 and whenever I  navigate to my bid page I see
TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default().models is undefined

my bid schema:
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const bidSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    bidder: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    item: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Item",
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Bid =
  mongoose.models.Bid || mongoose.model("Bid", bidSchema);

export default Bid;

I tried importing my connect() function to connect to the database in the associated server component:
import React from "react";
import Item from "@/models/Item";
import Form from "./Form";
import { GetDataFromToken } from "@/helpers/GetDataFromToken";
import { connect } from "@/helpers/DBConfig";
connect();

const page = async ({ params }) => {
  const { slug } = params;

  const item = await Item.findOne({ _id: slug });

  const user = GetDataFromToken();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{item?.name}</h1>
      <p>{item?.description}</p>
      <p>Starting bid: {item?.startingPrice}</p>
      <Form user={user.id} item={item._id} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default page;

but it was no help

What if you just do const Bid = mongoose.model("Bid", bidSchema);? Why are you checking if Bid is currently defined? when you use import, the file is executed only once, no need to check for that on the models

its the way we have to do it in  nextjs... something to do with  next being an edge based framework
